# How to remove all occurrences of repeated letters in a string, using regex. In JS

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to find a regex that returns all the repeated characters in a string, exept the first so that I can with a replace method exclude them from that string.

```
string = "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"

expectedOutput = "thequickbrownfxjmpsvlazydg"
```

I've seen many topics here about similar problems but none have managed to solve this problem.

Comment: reg exp is probably the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one regex option:

```js
string = "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog";
console.log(string);
string = string.split("").reverse().join("");
string = string.replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "");
string= string.split("").reverse().join("");
console.log(string);
```

The strategy here is to first reverse the string.  Then, we do a global regex replacement on the following pattern:

```
(.)(?=.*\1)
```

This will match any character which already appeared earlier in the string, and will check every character in the string.  So, for example, this has the effect of removing the `t` in the `thelazydog`, because `t` appeared earlier as the first character in the string.  Then, we reverse the string again to return it to the original order, after the regex replacement.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Variable width lookbehinds are not supported in all JavaScript engines, hence I did not suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter along with a `Set`; regular expressions are probably not the best tool for this task.

```js
let str = "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog";
let set = new Set;
let res = [...str].filter(c=>!set.has(c) && set.add(c)).join('');
console.log(res);
```

However, `Set` always retains insertion order, so we can simply pass the string to the `Set` constructor and convert it back to a string.

```js
let str = "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog";
let res = [...new Set(str)].join('');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let string = "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog";
let result = [];

for(i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    !result.includes(string[i]) ? result.push(string[i]) : 0;
}

let joined = result.join('');
console.log(joined);
```